# Which free video editing software do you recommend?

Tags: video-editor, freeware

I need to make a simple video for my current work and I am looking for a decent free video editing software. In the past I used Adobe Premiere and I am used to it. But I probably won't have to do any video editing in the future and it is not worth paying for a software. It would also be better if the software were not very simple, since I could use it also for more ambitious personal projects.

Comment: I suggest you can google it, my finding is https://www.lifewire.com/best-open-source-video-editing-software-4590219

Comment: If you search this site you'll see that this question has been asked and answered quite a few times.

Comment: Thank you xer-rex.

Comment: stib, I know, but the question was asked a couple of years ago and I suppose there is always something new or something better.